# Should I be using "me" or "I" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, subject-vs-object-pronouns

> There are my father, mother, grandparents, me who was seven years old, and my brother who was five years old.

The above sentence is used to describe a photograph. Is the sentence correct? Will it be "me" or "I"? Thanks

Comment: Some grammarians will insist the pronoun here should be ***I***, because it's a "nominative" usage (as the syntactic "subject" of the verb ***was** 7 yrs old*). But in practice most native speakers just use ***me*** anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I and John" vs. "John and myself" vs. "John and I" -- Which is the acceptable way to refer to myself and my friend?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59412/i-and-john-vs-john-and-myself-vs-john-and-i-which-is-the-acceptable-w)

Comment: Usually I try to decide such things by removing everything but the "me" case to simplify. So does the "are" become "am" or "is" when it's just me?  "There am I who was seven years old." "There is me who was seven years old." I don't really like either one. I would probably rewrite the whole thing.